# Server side execution (execution back-end image processing )

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I tried to build an web app with python django module. The task is If any one go to the link it will process image with threshold and save to server folder.

My code is(views.py):-

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import numpy as np
import cv2
import Image
from PIL import Image
import tesseract
import ctypes
import os
import ImageDraw



def index(request):
    im_gray = cv2.imread('Rimage.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    thresh = 100
    im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    cv2.imwrite('bw_image.png', im_bw)

    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

this code is not working error :-

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/meraj/Desktop/project/web/mysite/mysite/urls.py" in <module>
  5.     url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  28.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/meraj/Desktop/project/web/mysite/polls/urls.py" in <module>
  3. from polls import views

Exception Type: IndentationError at /polls/
Exception Value: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (views.py, line 20)
```

There is nothing wrong with my code as it is executing locally, but when i tried on django framework it  is not working. Am I going on correct direction ? I am new to python web framework so I don't have any idea about this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> "locally versus django framework".

Does this mean you are editing on one machine and copying the file to another? The problem is an IndentationEror, according to your output, so perhaps this is a space/tab or linebreak issue (one windows/one linux?) If the former, try replacing all tabs with spaces in your editor and ensuring you have the indentation correct after. If the latter, try a dos2unix on the file.

Comment: On Linux. Actually image is on the folder where views.py is situated. can you tell me all the module (numpy ,Image,PIL, ctypes) will wok if I imoprt them on views.py? @Wyrmwood

Comment: I can't with the information I have. However, the error appears to be a simple IndentationError, so changing your imports would probably not help (this particular issue).

Comment: django is a framework, and installs like a package, and imported into python. Yes, python should work with all those packages/imports together.